# How to build only one program in binutils

Tags: make, configure, binutils

Since there are many programs that are not related to my interests, I'd like to build a specific program in GNU `binutils` on Ubuntu.

Program means that one binary file (e.g., `ar`, `objcopy`)

for example, I'm interested in the `ar` among the `ar`, `objdump`, `objcopy`, `readelf`, ...

What should I do for this?

I've tried to remove other source code in `binutils-version/binutils/Makefile`

But, `Makefile` still produced object files for all programs
(`Makefile` also exists in `binutils-version/`)

Give me a fresh idea to build one program, please.

Comment: Did you find a way to build a "one program"? I'm building only objdump. What arguments I need to pass to `configure` to build only objdump (and required by objdump libraries)?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable building specific directories in the GNU binutils repository by calling `configure.sh` with `--disable-DIR` switches, as per [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037219/why-were-gnu-binutils-and-gdb-merged-as-one-package).

I don't know a way to enable/disable components more targeted, but when you use for example `--disable-gdb` and `--disable-ld`, this speeds up the build significantly.